# Android studio error: element value constant expression

Tags: android, json

i am trying to set a value of @GET if i put direct value my API call work fine but if i trying to get that value from other class it giving me error element value must be a constant expression

API http://49.12.80.197/Vokka/getclientbalance.do?pin=923338875585

if i write @GET("getclientbalance.do") API Call works fine

any solution for it >?

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class ApiClient {


    public static String BASE_URL = "http://49.12.80.197/Vokka/";
    public static String balance = "getclientbalance.do";
```

ApiInterface

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

import static com.kkdialer.voip.ApiClient.balance;

public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET(value = balance)
    Call<JsonElement> getclientbalance(@Query("pin") String mobileNo);

}
```

error: element value must be a constant expression
@GET(value = balance)

Comment: Are you using `Retrofit`?

Comment: yes i am using retrofit2.http.GET;

Comment: declare `balance` final -> `public static final String balance = "getclientbalance.do";`

Comment: if i declare then my other api will be effected because BASE_URL AND balance is not final , it always change from other json request example  
ApiClient.BASE_URL = jsonObject.getString("url");
ApiClient.balance = jsonObject.getString("email");
txt_brandName.setText(": " + jsonObject.getString("brand"));

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is a dynamic path for a request.

To cater that, `@Path` annotation has been provided by Retrofit, you can read more about it [here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html).

Use it as:

```
@GET("{path}")
Call<JsonElement> getclientbalance(
    @Query("pin") String mobileNo,
    @Path("path") String yourPath
);
```

The purpose of `@Path` is to provide dynamic request URLs. For example, a separate request URL based on user's username.

It, also, has the functionality to encode or not encode the URLs, read the link provided above to know more.

Comment: if i put @Path("path") String yourPath in call that will be disturb my call result , as example api url http://49.12.80.197/Vokka/ @GET ("getclientbalance.do") and Query("pin") String mobileNo , thats work fine in this way , i want only GET VALUE FROM STRING